# What is the opposite of -genic?

Tags: single-word-requests, suffixes, word-formation

English uses the [suffix -genic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_words_suffixed_with_-genic) to mean "generating / generated by / producing":

- anxiogenic (anxiety-producing)
- iatrogenic (caused by the healer / doctor)
- neurogenic (produced by the nervous system)

What would the opposite suffix be? Something that means, approximately "the presence of this inhibits" or "exclusive from".

Comment: Probably -lytic:of, relating to, or causing 'lysis': the gradual subsiding of the symptoms of an acute disease. Anxiolytic, neurolytic.

Comment: I understand a something-inhibitor, but what do you mean by "exclusive from"?  Free of?

Comment: `The opposite of` is not really very well defined, and _-genic_ is **way** too complex a concept to have any "opposite". Opposites are for simple concepts arrayed in one dimension, like _hot/cold, warm/cool, high/low_. Add more abstractions, plus time development and causation, and you don't have opposition any more -- you have a non-commutative matrix with seventeen dimensions of variance.

Comment: "Stat" - Suffix meaning (among other things) an "agent for stopping the growth of": bacteriostat, mycostat, fungistat. - Mosby's Medical Dictionary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Came here to provide the same answer as the one Josh61 put in his comment.

The answer is most certainly ['-lytic'](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-lytic)

[Anxiolytic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anxiolytic)

[Neurolysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neurolysis)